# Работа со строкой в C#

Tags: строки, c#

Суть в том что надо ввести слово (к примеру asdfgh123) и из слова убрать все буквы кроме цифр. Думал сделать так, но не пашет. )

```
using System;

class Stroka
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите слово");
        string stroka = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введенное слово:{0}", stroka);
        Console.WriteLine("Введите часть слова котрую надо убрать ");
        string del = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Результат ", ss.Remove(del));
    }
}
```

Comment: Изначальная строка - stroka, а убирается кусок из ss. Что вообще такое ss? 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var inputString = "asdfgh1223453456253463";
      var match = Regex.Match(inputString, @"[0-9][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?");
      if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Matched nums: {0}", match.Value);
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Nums not found.");
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

Более подробно о регулярных выражениях можно почитать в статье [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

А [вот тут](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) можно использовать удобный подборщик/справочник по регулярным выражениям.

Comment: это я что то не так сделал там вместо ss должно было быть stroka).